# How to identify previous scheduled date and next scheduled date among many dates in scheduled table via procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have one table which is containing scheduled dates like 01/01/2015, 01/02/2015, 01/03/2015, 01/04/2015, 01/05/2015....

Based on today's date i have to identify what is previous schedule date and next schedule date via stored procedure.

For example today's date is 25/03/2015. Then previous schedule date is 01/02/2015 and next schedule date is 01/04/2015.

Is there any SQL query to identify this scenario.

I am using Oracle database.

Comment: And what are the rules/logic to derive your desied dates? Your question is incomplete. Please edit and add the required details to the question.

Comment: Do you always want the previous/next months's first date?

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B - dates may be different but not exactly months's first date. Date to date one month will be there.

Comment: Then you must provide the required details as I asked you in the very first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the previous date, get maximum date that is less than today. And for the next date, find the minimum date that is greater than today.

Previous:

```
SELECT max(scheduled_date) from schedule_table where scheduled_date < sysdate;
```

Next:

```
SELECT min(scheduled_date) from schedule_table where scheduled_date > sysdate;
```

Extract the day or date from the returned value as necessary.